# Target specific div with pseudo element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, flexbox

I'am trying to simply target the third div in my html with a class of `.counter-wrap`. On a mobile device this div has a `margin-bottom` of 40px. I want to remove the margin-bottom on the third stacked div named `.counter-wrap`.

I thought I could simply do `.counter-wrap: last-of-type` but the reason this doesn't work I believe is because each .counter-wrap is in its own `.col` class. Can this be done with a pseudo element or would I be better off just using a unique id on the last `.counter-wrap` div and just apply `margin-bottom: 0`?

```css
body {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container,
.container-long {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.counter-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.counter-text,
.counter-number {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}

.counter-text {
  letter-spacing: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.counter-number {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please mark and upvote if that worked well for you?

Comment: The given answers has one big flaw, the second you i.e. add a 4th `col` for  some additional info, they all break. Setting a class on the one you want to target will always work.

Comment: Yes i am fully aware thanks for pointing it out though. I wont be adding anymore 'cols' so it should be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `last-of-type` selector on the `col` class like this:

```
.col:last-of-type .counter-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
body {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container,
.container-long {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.counter-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

/*ADDED*/
.col:last-of-type .counter-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.counter-text,
.counter-number {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}

.counter-text {
  letter-spacing: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.counter-number {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple. Works a treat

Answer (score 2):

Please check the updated code. You only need to update this css rest you will get the desired result.

```
.wrap .col:last-child .counter-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.wrap {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container,
.container-long {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.counter-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.counter-text,
.counter-number {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}

.counter-text {
  letter-spacing: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.counter-number {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight: 500;

}

.wrap .col:last-child .counter-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="counter-wrap">
          <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
          <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
          <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `nth-child()` rule. Apply it to the parent element and then input the number of which child class you wish to target. In this case it would be

```
.col:nth-child(3) .counter-wrap {
background:red;
}
```

```css
    body {
      color: black;
      font-size: 15px;
    }

    .wrap {
      width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .container,
    .container-long {
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto
    }

    .row {
      margin-left: -15px;
      margin-right: -15px;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .col {
      position: relative;
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
      flex-basis: 100%;
    }


    .counter-wrap {
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    .counter-text,
    .counter-number {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: black;
    }

    .counter-text {
      letter-spacing: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
    }

    .counter-number {
      font-size: 60px;
      font-weight: 500;

    }


    .col:nth-child(3) .counter-wrap {
      background:red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="counter-wrap">
              <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
              <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
              <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="counter-wrap">
              <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
              <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
              <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="counter-wrap">
              <span class="counter-text">Line1</span>
              <span class="counter-number count">1234</span>
              <span class="counter-text">Line 2</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```